# Conbining CSS and JavaScript into one file and link it

Tags: javascript, css, bundle

I developed a small online application that has the obvious jQuery, BootStrap, other third party libraries plus CSS files as well as my customized CSS and JavaScript but wanted to bundle them together to I have only one call.

The reason is because this application is being used with several online websites that already have those libraries but may have an outdated library which mine will over ride theirs which will cause the websites not to work properly.

I used the HTML imports by placing all my libraries and CSS into one HTML file, called it import.html and make a simple  `<link rel="http://mywebsite.com/import"></link>` and it worked like a charm but it didn't work in iOS. Oh yes this is a smart phone only application and only for iOS and Android.

But the main reason is that I will be handing the files to the clients and wanted to give the less code as possible for easy implementation.

Is there another method to accomplishing a similar scenario?

Comment: Technically you could have just a JS file that included some code to load some CSS (by appending the HTML for it). You're not saving HTTP calls that way (there is no way to do that) but someone would only need to add one thing to their HTML. Edit: this doesn't address the overriding thing, no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: How does bundling prevent yours from overriding theirs? It should not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce arbitrary HTML/CSS into HTML through JavaScript.

For example:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
var CSS = ".someCSS { background: red; }";
style.innerHTML = CSS; 
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

This approach is useful for programmatically modifying and introducing CSS, but it's definitely a lot slower than including CSS with the `<link>` element. (This method makes it hard to edit CSS, and requires the bypasses any browser optimizations in the construction of the DOM and Style tables)

Also, you have a mistake in your post, **iOS, Android, and most every browser, can definitely include CSS with `<link rel = "...">`**. This is considered the *right* away to do it and is faster than the code I posted above (which was the answer to your question). The reason why your code isn't working is NOT an issue with CSS/HTML on iOS and more is likely an issue with your site itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I look up the iOS by using [ http://caniuse.com/#search=import ] and it shows iOS does not support the import tag.

Comment: My apologies, I thought you meant you couldn't link CSS sheets. I'm sorry for my answer not being useful